# Is there any way to set year in crontab parameter list?

Tags: linux, cron

I want to set a cronjob for a specific date and time. 
For example, date time like this 2017 July 12, 12 35.
Is it possible to set Year in the crontab parameter list?
I can set without the year field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Crontab is for events that REPEAT on cycles within the year. It's got no capacity for scheduling events on a particular year, nor even for events that happen in some years and not others. It's just not something the designers of cron needed to do.

Comment: Yes got the answer. Thank you.

Comment: This is pretty frustrating when working with AWS because they require a year parameter so CRONTAB can help you get started but it won't give you the fully correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There is no parameter to specify the year in crontab.

You can move the year logic to the bash script and add that script to crontab.